# JS prototypical function 'this' confusion

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm using a JSON-RPC lib in nodejs. I register my functions by name (e.g. `rpc({publicName: privateFunction})`) and the RPC lib invokes the functions for me and handles marshalling the JSON and function arguments. It works great for simple functions but it breaks when I pass it a prototypical function (a function defined on the prototype chain of an object). The problem is the RPC lib is invoking the function using `apply` which alters the context of `this` so I can no longer access the other prototype properties / functions.

Here is an example of the problem:

```
var MyObj = function(prop1,prop2,prop3){
    this.prop1 = prop1;
    this.prop2 = prop2;
    this.prop3 = prop3;
}

MyObj.prototype.showProps = function(separator){
    console.log(this.prop1 + separator + this.prop2 + separator + this.prop3);
}

var myObjInstance = new MyObj('a', 'b', 'c');
myObjInstance.showProps(',');

// displays a,b,c


// I register the function as rpc({show_props:myObjInstance.showProps}) and the RPC lib calls it like
myObjInstance.showProps.apply(this, [',']);

// displays undefined,undefined,undefined
```

Is there a better technique to fix this? Is there a way to preserve the context of `this` inside the prototypical function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind a specific context to a function. It’s not avail in all environments, but there is a shim on the MDN page that you can use if you need legacy support.

So in your example you could add:

```
myObjInstance.showProps = myObjInstance.showProps.bind(myObjInstance);
```

Comment: It is available in nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line:

```
myObjInstance.showProps.apply(this, [',']);
```

`this` points to the global scope (or whatever scope you're in at that point, it does **not** point to `myObjInstance`). You should call it like this:

```
myObjInstance.showProps.apply(myObjInstance, [',']);
```

The first argument is the context, which should be your object instance.

Comment: my understanding was that that was library code and outside his control